# CSS Two Column Full High with Fixed Footer?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a layout with 4 divs; a header, a footer, and a left and right column.

The header should be at the top, fill the whole width, and be 50px high.
The footer should be fixed to the bottom of the window, also 50px high.
The left and right divs should be next to each other, and fill all of the space (vertically) between the bottom of the header and the top of the footer.

This seems like it should be extremely simple, but I've spent the past 5 hours on this and can't get it to work right.

The best I could do was this:

```
<body>
  <div class="BodyWrapper">
    <div id="Header"></div><!-- End Header -->         
     <div class="Left LeftColumn">asds</div>
     <div class="Right RightColumn"></div>         
     <div class="push"></div>         
  </div><!-- End Body -->
  <div id="Footer"></div><!-- End Footer -->
```

CSS:

```
 *{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  }

  html, body {
  height:100%;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:11px;
  color:#646464;
  }

  .BodyWrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  }

  #Footer, .push {
  height: 4em;
  }

  .Left {
  float:left;
  }

  .Right {
  float:right;
  }

  .LeftColumn {
     width:20%;
     height:100%;
     margin-bottom:-52px;
     border:1px solid gray;
     background:red;   
  }

  .RightColumn {
     width:70%;
     height:100%;
     margin-bottom:-52px;
     border:1px solid gray;
     background:green;
  }


  #Header {
  height:49px;
  background:blue;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  }

  #Footer {
  height:49px;
  background:blue;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  }
```

The result of this is *almost* what I want, but the left and right columns go all the way to the bottom of the page and cover the footer. What I really want is to give them a hight of 100% minus 50px. Any suggestions? Or an example of this that works?

Comment: This article should help: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/how_to_create_a_3-column_layout_with_css/ And this one too: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/flexible-3column.html

Comment: I'd recommend checking out http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/holy-grail-liquid-layout-no-quirks-mode

Comment: That's a good resource but  I didn't see one with a fixed footer.

Comment: actually there is http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, i know - tables are evil. But they work wonderfully here! All the height and width issues are taken care of by the implementation of the table itself.

```
<table>
<tr id="header">
<td>Header Stuff</td>
</tr>
<tr id="cols">
<td style="width:20%" id="leftcol">Left col Stuff</td>
<td style="width:80%" id="rightcol">Right Col Stuff</td>
</tr>
<tr id="footer">
<td>Copyright Whatever footer stuff</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So far this looks like the best option. As "wrong" as table may be, this seems to "just work". I'll wait a little bit longer to see if someone has a pure div/css solution, but if not, I'm going to accept this answer and go with it!

Comment: @Nick thanks. I'm a big fan of tables for layout and it annoys me to pieces when people bash it. Glad you appreciate it.

Comment: @ Downvoter care to explain? I don't mind losing rep but i like to know why so i can improve.

Comment: So far this is giving me what I'm looking for with very little pain. The mark-up is a bit heavier, but not by too much. But most importantly, it works! So I can get on with building my application. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you allow jquery to aid you in this process, it will be greatly simplified.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/robx/G8aWv/5/

Comment: Jquery? I don't see any JavaScript in your example?

Comment: there was some. Sorry let me fix it. maybe forgot to hit update before putting link here.

Comment: I'm still not seeing an Java Script, but it seems to be mostly working without it... The only issue is with really long text like the other poster mentioned. ie. http://jsfiddle.net/d9RrT/9/ If the text is too long it should be hidden, or the column should scroll.

Comment: sorry, honestly i don't know why it is not saving up updating. See updated. I have deleted that old jsfiddle and added a new one. This time I have closed and opened the site a few times to check myself. So hopefully it doesn't do that again.

Comment: That's in interesting solution, but you would have to call the resize function every time the window size changes. And it's still doing some bizarre things when the content gets too long.

Comment: Perhaps set that height as max-height with overflow auto to scroll.

Comment: I've set a more detailed update of something real simple you can do. Does recall resize every time the window size changes, but I don't know of any other way other solutions to be fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the clear property for your footer div. For example:

#Footer {
  clear:both;
  height:49px;
  background:blue;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  }

Comment: clear:both would push the footer down, but I'd like the footer "pinned" to the bottom of the window, with the columns filling all of the space in between.